# MYSQL Double Counting Sum

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am trying to sum the views from the impression table but the answer of some are doubling because there are more than 1 flight for some of the campaigns.

I am combining the data from 3 different tables. 
**Is there something I can do so only one row from the flight table is returned?**

```
SELECT CAMPAIGN_CPM, CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID, CAMPAIGN_NAME, MONTHNAME(IMP_DATE), SUM(VIEWS),  CONCAT(MONTH(IMP_DATE),'-',YEAR(IMP_DATE)) AS MonthYear
FROM IMPRESSION 
INNER JOIN CAMPAIGN
ON IMPRESSION.CAMPAIGN_ID = CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID
INNER JOIN FLIGHT
ON FLIGHT.CAMPAIGN_ID = CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID
WHERE MONTH(IMP_DATE) = MONTH(now() - interval 1 MONTH) AND CAMPAIGN_CPM > 0 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(IMP_DATE), IMPRESSION.CAMPAIGN_ID, CAMPAIGN_CPM;
```

If any other information is need please let me know.

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `FLIGHT` (
  `FLIGHT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FLIGHT_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLIGHT_START_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLIGHT_END_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_FREQUENCY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_FREQUENCY_PERIOD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_CPM` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOM_CAMPAIGN_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FLIGHT_ID`),
  KEY `CAMPAIGN` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CAMPAIGN_FK4` FOREIGN KEY (`CAMPAIGN_ID`) REFERENCES `CAMPAIGN` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `IMPRESSION` (
  `IMP_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BANNER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADVERTISER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLACEMENT_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS_WITH_DEFAULTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS_WITHOUT_DEFAULTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VIEWS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEFAULTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLICKS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSION_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IMPRESSION_ID`),
  KEY `CAMPAIGN_ID` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`),
  KEY `BANNER_ID` (`BANNER_ID`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_ID` (`CUSTOMER_ID`),
  KEY `ADVERTISER_ID` (`ADVERTISER_ID`),
  KEY `PLACEMENT_ID` (`PLACEMENT_ID`),
  KEY `CAMPAIGN_ID_2` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `DSF` FOREIGN KEY (`PLACEMENT_ID`) REFERENCES `PLACEMENT` (`PLACEMENT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ADVERTISER_FK9` FOREIGN KEY (`ADVERTISER_ID`) REFERENCES `ADVERTISER` (`ADVERTISER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `BANNER_FK5` FOREIGN KEY (`BANNER_ID`) REFERENCES `BANNER` (`BANNER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CAMPAIGN_FK3` FOREIGN KEY (`CAMPAIGN_ID`) REFERENCES `CAMPAIGN` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_FK5` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`CUSTOMER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35673 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `CAMPAIGN` (
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_START_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_END_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADVERTISER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CAMPAIGN_ID`),
  KEY `ADVERTISER` (`ADVERTISER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `ADVERTISER_FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`ADVERTISER_ID`) REFERENCES `ADVERTISER` (`ADVERTISER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Table structure would be nice. Table structure and sample data even nicer. Make a Sqlfiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: The impression table contains the views and campaign id. The flight table contains the campaign id. The campaign table contains the campaign name and campaign id. Does that help?

Comment: Use the command "show  create table" to recreate the table structure and post it in you question.

Comment: Tables used in the example are above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have added FLIGHT to show that one flight number is shown and I changed the location from views.

**SQL code:**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT FLIGHT.FLIGHT_ID, SUM(VIEWS), CAMPAIGN_CPM, CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID, CAMPAIGN_NAME, MONTHNAME(IMP_DATE),  CONCAT(MONTH(IMP_DATE),'-',YEAR(IMP_DATE)) AS MonthYear
FROM IMPRESSION 
INNER JOIN CAMPAIGN
ON IMPRESSION.CAMPAIGN_ID = CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID
INNER JOIN FLIGHT
ON FLIGHT.CAMPAIGN_ID = CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_ID
WHERE MONTH(IMP_DATE) = MONTH(now() - interval 1 MONTH) AND CAMPAIGN_CPM > 0 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(IMP_DATE), IMPRESSION.CAMPAIGN_ID, CAMPAIGN_CPM
) a GROUP BY a.CAMPAIGN_ID;
```

I have made some small alterations because I had to fill the tables with sample data. Furthermore, the there were some issues with the primary keys and cascading. However, Every should work in your version.

**TABLE structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `FLIGHT` (
  `FLIGHT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `FLIGHT_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLIGHT_START_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLIGHT_END_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_FREQUENCY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_FREQUENCY_PERIOD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_CPM` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOM_CAMPAIGN_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `IMPRESSION` (
  `IMP_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BANNER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADVERTISER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLACEMENT_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS_WITH_DEFAULTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS_WITHOUT_DEFAULTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VIEWS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEFAULTS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLICKS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSION_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35673 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `CAMPAIGN` (
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `CAMPAIGN_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_START_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_END_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**SAMPLE Data:**

```
INSERT INTO FLIGHT (FLIGHT_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID,CAMPAIGN_CPM)
VALUES (255060,1,250),
(255080,1,250),
(255070,1,250),
(255020,1,40),
(255025,2,300),
(255040,3,250),
(255045,3,20),
(255046,3,100),
(255071,4,210),
(255055,5,280);

INSERT INTO IMPRESSION (IMP_DATE,CAMPAIGN_ID, VIEWS)
VALUES 
((NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY),1,250),
((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),2,4050),
((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),3,10),
((NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY),3,40),
((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),3,10),
((NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY),4,40),
((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),5,1350);

INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID, CAMPAIGN_NAME)
VALUES 
(1,'jkajoiuwejoijdkjjklja'),
(2,'ajiuiouwoihajdhjhhjh'),
(3, 'aauuehxbhchuhnb'),
(4,'aduuiuhzjcnckjnxkj'),
(5,'zzzdfhjfhajkhwkjeajqw');
```

Here is a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34717/1) demo. Try it out. Good luck with you project.

Comment: @cartoom02 have you looked at my answer?